# How to change Facebook personal URL; error: Already has alias

Tags: facebook

I have a custom URL for my personal page titled: `facebook.com/my.name`.

When I go to change this custom url to be not my name (trying to evade employer search and e-discovery I guess), it says:

> "There was an error while setting your username: Already has alias."

Note, I have already changed my profile name. Any ideas here?

I made sure my password is correct as well.

Comment: Have you tried a) removing the alias first or b) checking that the new name isn't used by someone else?

Comment: I have a) name that has been changed but the term "alias" does not show up anywhere except in this error dialogue. Also, the b) new name is not used by anyone else. They have some ajax'y error checking that hits their DB and looks to see if the new name is in use and tells you immediately if it is or not

Comment: It seems there is a problem on their end: https://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=125713384123802&topic=2448

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted the answer to this problem under a [Facebook thread](https://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=125713384123802), I thought I would  share what that person had to say.

*This solution will only work for those who have accidentally set their vanity for their personal profile instead of their page.*

- Go to the [username infringement form](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=username_infringement)
- State the situation, and that you would like your name changed from the profile to the Facebook Page and hopefully they will make the change